# set adjustable listView between two hardcoded items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to set list view between two hardcoded items. I can't leave the height value blank in listView, cause it's disappear. I try with wrap/fill.. but all this things making my listView fill whole layout. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/choose_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1" >
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buton_style" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addToBasketName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Produkty:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/choose_produkty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Do zapłaty:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/choose_do_zaplaty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addToBasket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Do kasy" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/choose_list_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
  android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"  >
```

Answer (score 1):

By default , all your Views will be placed at the top left corner in your `RelativeLayout`. So you will usually want to add `layout_below` or `layout_top` to your component.

For a more detail description for `RelativeLayout`, see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Comment: yeah, thx for comment, I don't know why I forgot about below nad top parameters, and trying to set in by some weird methods :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinearLayout` as the outmost container, and setthis to the `ListView`:

```
layout_height="0px
layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/choose_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addToBasketName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Produkty:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/choose_produkty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Do zapłaty:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/choose_do_zaplaty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addToBasket"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Do kasy" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```